# Turfjs buffer + Leaflet return Uncaught _u {}

Tags: leaflet, buffer, turf

I'm trying to set a buffer with turfjs in a polygon. The polygon is loaded by `L.geoJSON();` . When I execute bufferConcesion, this line `var turfBuffer = turf.buffer(feature,value,{units:"kilometers"});` returns this error: `Uncaught _u {}` What might bethe problem.

This is my code:

```
    var featLayer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
        style:{
            weight: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            color: 'red'
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            layer.on('contextmenu',popUpBuffer);
        }
    });

    function popUpBuffer(e){
        var id = e.target.feature.properties.id;
        var popup = L.popup()
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("<table><tr><td>Buffer (KM): </td><td><input type='text' id='buffer_value'><input type='hidden' id='ca_id' value='"+id+"'/></td><td><button onclick='bufferConcesion()'>Go</button></td></tr></table>")
            .openOn(map); 
    }
    function bufferConcesion(){
        var value = document.getElementById("buffer_value").value;
        if(value!==""){
            var layer = L.geoJSON(data,{
                filter:isID,
                onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                    var turfBuffer = turf.buffer(feature,value,{units:"kilometers"});
                    var turfBufferLyr = L.geoJSON(turfBuffer, {style:{color:'yellow',dashArray:'5.5',fillOpacity:0}}).addTo(featLayer);
                }
            }).addTo(featLayer);
        }

    }
    function isID(feature){
        var id = document.getElementById("ca_id").value;
        if (feature.properties.id === id) return true
    }
```

Comment: What does a feature look like if you log one, like `console.log(feature)` in your onEachFeature function?

Comment: like this: http://prntscr.com/hzaffe

Answer (score 1):

Turf doesn't see Leaflet layers as GeoJSON. When I had roads as a leaflet layer this worked.

```
var buffered = turf.buffer(road.toGeoJSON(), 2, {units: 'miles'});
```

In your code try:

```
var turfBuffer = turf.buffer(feature.toGeoJSON(),value,{units:"kilometers"});
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you Bill. I tried before with that code, but showed me another error: `Uncaught TypeError: feature.toGeoJSON is not a function`.

Comment: apparently it has to do with polygons. I copied a piece of code from turf (buffer a point) and pasted in my project and works fine. But then a changed to `'type':'Polygon'` and added the coordinates and then returns `Uncaught _u {}`